# Loading .npy files as dataset for pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, pytorch

I have preprocessed data in .npy files, let's call it X.npy for raw data and Y.npy for labels. They're organized to match every element from both files (first element from X has first label from Y etc.). How can I load it as dataset using `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`? I'm very new to pytorch, and any help will be useful.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use DatasetFolder, which basically is the underlying class of ImageFolder. Using this class you can provide your own file extensions and loader to load the samples.

```py
def npy_loader(path):
    return torch.from_numpy(np.load(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

All codes are listed below:

```
def npy_loader(path):
    sample = torch.from_numpy(np.load(path))
    return sample
    

dataset = datasets.DatasetFolder(
    root='PATH',
    loader=npy_loader,
    extensions=['.npy']
)
```